# How do I create an app I can "Share" a URL to in Android?

Tags: android, url, sdk, android-intent, share

Please can someone explain in Plain English how I create an app that Android can then offer as a target if I "Share" a URL from within the device's browser?

I'm finding Google's official SDK documentation near-impenetrable, and (so far) lacking in any real world examples relevant to passing a URL from the browser into another application. **:-(**

I would be really grateful for any advice people might be able to offer; feels like I'm slamming my head against a big, green, brick wall right about now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You want to create an application that can handle [`ACTION_SEND`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) intents and then register an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs) in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I copied the following example from Android's default Mms application's [manifest](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Mms.git;a=blob;f=AndroidManifest.xml;h=88c9a72ffe743960f698f97e1e08ad21981a586f;hb=HEAD):

```
<activity android:name=".ui.ComposeMessageActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- ... -->
</activity>
```

Comment: Many thanks, Josef! As my app will only work with URLs, should I change the mimeType definition to something like "text/url"?

Answer (score -1):

Needed to implement it in a simple way in my application and decided as follows:

```
String strUrl = "http://example.com";
Intent shareUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareUrl.setType("text/plain");
shareUrl.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strUrl);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareURL,"Share with..."));
```

This is the simplest way that you can do to share some content of your app with other apps on your device. Practical and functional.

Comment: Thanks, but my need was for an app that could listen for the global sharing event and be available as a target. I'm not trying to share content out from my application, it just needed to capture content and pass it on to a web service if the user selected it as an option from the standard Android "Share" dialogue within another application.